# Create theme file for content type?

Tags: 7, theming

In Drupal 6, if you had a content type with the system name "stock-photo", you could override it using:

```
node-stock-photo.tpl.php
```

How do you do this in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom `node.tpl.php` for any kind of content type like

```
node--[node-type].tpl.php
```

I would suggest you to use hook suggestion at `template.php` for this :

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {  // Add theme suggestion for all content types
    if (isset($variables['node'])) {
        if ($variables['node']->type != '') {
            $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__node__' . $variables['node']->type;
        }
    }
}
```

So that I can have `node--wine.tpl.php` for content type **wine**.

Note -- Don't forget to clear your cache after this :)

Comment: What's the purpose of the PHP hook suggestion function?

Answer (score 5):

I think `MYTHEME_preprocess_page()` function doesn't need for it.

The `node--[node-type].tpl.php` is only enough for it.

Comment: That worked for me :)